# Get number of new sales based on previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, calculation

Assuming Table A has an Area_Key, Date_Sold, and a Sale_ID,
Here is what my query looks like to calculate # of Monthly Sales

```
SELECT a.AreaKey,
    dbo.BOMONTH(a.[DateSold]) [Period],
    COUNT(a.Sale_ID) [Sales]
FROM TableA a
GROUP BY a.AreaKey, dbo.BOMONTH(a.[DateSold])
```

Here is what the results look like
[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiZhg.png)

I use `dbo.BOMONTH(date)` to group them in month, for in the table they are not grouped

Objective: How can I calculate the number of new sales based on the previous month?

I can see there are similarly named questions, but I can't find one that matches my situation.

Expectation:

| AreaKey | Period | NewSaleAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04025 | 2022-08-01 | 7 |
| 04025 | 2022-09-01 | 2 |

- If the subtraction is a negative value, as in previous month has more sales than current, then 0.
- I'm thinking that this is a subtraction calculation, like NewSaleAmount = Sales for that area key per month - Sales for that area key per month-1 . but I'm not sure how to do that
- I can see from other questions like mine that would use LAG, but I'm not sure how that's applicable to my problem
- I think if I put the original query in a subquery called temp, I would be able to do something like this but it doesn't work. Am I on the right track?

ex: if (random key) had 5 total sales in April, and 10 in may, there would be 5 new sales for may

```
SELECT temp.AreaKey,
    temp.Period,
    NewSaleAmount = (temp.Sales - (select temp.sales where temp.Period = DATEADD(MONTH,-1,temp.Period)))
FROM (subquery above) temp
```

Comment: Hi - 1) please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text 2) please tag your question with the DBMS you are using 3) what is your definition of a new sale?

Comment: @NickW 1)Im not sure how to add my query results as an editable text 
3) The NewSaleAmount would be the positive difference between: Month's Sale amount - Previous Month's Sale amount (per AreaKey)
The first query first gathers the amount of sales for that month per AreaKey

Comment: `with data as (<your query) select *, case when Sales - lag(Sales) over (order by Period) > 0 then Sales - lag(Sales) over (order by Period) else 0 end from data;`

Comment: Please don't edit your question to says its been answered - if you think the answer will be useful to someone else either encourage the commenter to add an answer, or add one yourself. If you don't think its useful, then just delete the question.

Comment: You add editable text to your question by copy/paste or by typing it in - the same way that you’ve added all the other editable text to your question